# Have GCC preprocessor treat angle brackets as quotes

Tags: g++, c-preprocessor, hdf5, gcc7

I'm trying to make use of system headers that make use of angle-brackets where quotes should have been used. Specifically I have a system-supplied header file in /usr/include/hdf5/serial/ which contains

```
#include <hdf5.h>
```

I could of course pass G++ the option *-isystem /usr/include/hdf5/serial*, but I'd rather keep things modular, and not replicate this piece of configuration to any project that could ultimately consume this header.

I'm using G++ 7.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 and CentOS 7.x with DevToolset 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you propose is the only sensible solution - the library requires you to add that directory to the compiler's system-includes path.  To isolate that from programs using your headers, you could forward-declare just the things you need from the library, or you might need some sort of abstraction layer.  Or just forward the library's `pkg-config` in your own library's `.pc` file.

Comment: Thanks for turning my attention to pkg-config. It does make the process easier...